# Xilinx eprom flashing fails with various errors

Tags: xilinx, vivado, zynq, flashing

**Symptom:** When I select "program flash" menu from the IDE, it starts working, but fails on a random point. Sometimes it erases flash successfully, sometimes fails earlier (see logs below).

**History:** It was working for weeks. When I uploaded my program, it was running, printing stuff to the UART port. Then, a nice day, flashing has stopped. I've tried, but it printed various errors. Next day it was working again (without any fix), but only for 2-3 days, then stopped working *forever*.

**Diagnosis:** In Vivado, I can see the device, it looks healthy. I checked `.bat` scripts, they set the environment and finally calls `rdi_zynq_flash.exe`, which is responsible for the whole flashing process (using server on localhost). From this point, I have no chance to know what is really happening under the hood. I was playing around with the `XSCT` tool, but I have no idea what should I check.

**Configuration:**

- Board: Xilinx Zynq 7000, ZC702
- IDE: Vivaldo 2020.1, on Windows 10
- program type: standalone (not Linux), only ARM code, no FPGA used
- programming mode: QSPI (switch 4 is on, others are off)

**The errors are:**

- unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: 10, 01, 00
- unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: 68, 03, 00
- Failed to read boot mode register
- ERROR: Flash Operation Failed
- zynq_qspi_irq_poll: Timeout

See [full logs](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ern0/1e3046bcce13c7cd1206bac1baa485c3/raw/6c242bfc9205b60a51e237bef675fd6260628317/gistfile1.txt) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Solved *automatically*. I don't know why, I moved some cables, turned switches on and off. Maybe, it was a hardware issue.

If you have better answer, please, leave here.